# Windows Batch ask for fileformat then search files from list and copy to directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made batch that search in folder structure for file `mama1.jpg` but I need it to ask user for file extension (eg. png, cr2 etc.)

Is it possible?

```
SET destination=%CD%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find "mama.jpg"') do (
if not exist "Skopiowane_zdjecia" md "Skopiowane_zdjecia"
xcopy /y "%%a" "%destination%/Skopiowane_zdjecia")
```

Comment: Note that changing the extension does not convert the file to another format. (Painting a red box to blue doesn't change its content.) Renaming might render the files to be unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /p ext="Type file format you search for (eg: jpg, cr2, nef): 

SET destination=%CD%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find "mama.%ext%"') do (
if not exist "Skopiowane_zdjecia" md "Skopiowane_zdjecia"
xcopy /y "%%a" "%destination%/Skopiowane_zdjecia")
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the purpose of using `find.exe`. Also you could replace lines `4`, `5`, `6` and `7` with a single line: ```For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "mama.%ext%" /B /S /A:-D 2^>NUL') Do %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%%G" "Skopiowane_zdjecia\" /Y```.